# Perl - Searching many xml files with pre-caching - architectural consideration

Tags: xml, perl, caching, search

How to search/filter in the many XML files? (200K files, approx each 20-40KB size). This should be done in the web-app, therefore need as fast as possible method.

Need search not only for specified XML-tag,

- but filter the result based on the content of some tags (e.g. display files what are newer as `<created>timpestamp</created>`)
- or fulltext in some tags like `<content>full text here</content>`
- the data *must* be in the XML files (can only use a sort of caching)

Thinking about the working solution:

- use something like XML::Simple or XML::Twig in a cycle over 200K files is slow, therefore
- need cache them for the fast access - convert all XML files into some "DB" (probably NoSQL)
- For what I should looking and learn? MongoDB or something other has nice support in the **perl** for the search/filter task?
- what should I avoid/beware and to what need pay attention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about this, but I think you are looking for some kind of [XML Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database).

If the above doesn't fit your needs, you could always parse your new/updated XMLs, store them as indexed documents in a [`Sphinx`](http://sphinxsearch.com/) server and when your users are doing the searches, serve the documents based on it - it is really fast and works smoothly with millions of documents

Comment: Thanx for pointers - will try XML Database. And Sphinx is interesting idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Reading that many files is always going to be slow.

You need to index those files, the way a search engine does.

Read them all once, index them, put the index into a database, then re-index them if and when they change.

Answer (score 0):

What about reading the files with `XML::LibXML` and saving the resulting structures with `Storable` to create the cache? Is reading Storable files still too slow?

Comment: Reading 200K files is slow in any form, and build one big hash with all XML files need 6+ GB memory...